# Dynamically storing an internal configuration

Tags: c++, design-patterns, configuration

I've been thinking of `The Right Way (R)` to store my program's internal configuration.

Here's the details:

- The configuration is runtime only, so generated each run.
- It can be adapted (and should) through directives in a "project" file (the reading of that file is not in the scope of this question)
- It needs to be extensible, ie there should be a way to add new "variables" with assignes values.

My questions about this:

1. How should I begin with this? Is a
   class with accessors and setters
   with an internal `std::map` for
   custom variables a good option?
2. Are there any known and "good" ways
   of doing this?
3. Should there be a difference between
   integer, boolean and string
   configuration variables?
4. Should there be a difference at all
   between user and built-in
   (pre-existing as in I already
   thought of them) variables?

Thanks!

PS: If the question isn't clear, feel free to ask for more info.

**UPDATE**: Wow, every answer seems to have implicitely or explicitly used boost. I should have mentioned I'd like to avoid boost (I want to explore the Standard libraries' capabilities as is for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do worse than some kind of a property map (`StringMap` is just a typedef'd std::map)

```
class PropertyMap
{
private:
    StringMap m_Map;

public:
    PropertyMap() { };
            ~PropertyMap() { };

    // properties
    template<class T>
    T get(const String& _key, const T& _default = T()) const
    {
        StringMap_cit cit(m_Map.find(_key));
        return (cit != m_Map.end()) ? boost::lexical_cast<T>(cit->second) : _default;
    };  // eo get

    // methods
    void set(const String& _cap, const String& _value)
    { 
        m_Map[_cap] = _value;
    };  // eo set

    template<class T>
    void set(const String& _key, const T& _val)
    {
        set(_key, boost::lexical_cast<String>(_val));
    };  // eo set
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) for this.

> Property trees are versatile data
>   structures, but are particularly
>   suited for holding configuration data.
>   The tree provides its own,
>   tree-specific interface, and each node
>   is also an STL-compatible Sequence for
>   its child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It is very useful to support nesting in configuration files. Something like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example).

As parameter values can be scalars, arrays and nested groups of parameters, it could be stored in a `std::map` of `boost::variant`'s, whose value can be a scalar, array or other `std::map` recursively. Note that `std::map` sorts by name, so if the original config file order of parameters is important there should be a sequential index of parameters as well. This can be achieved by using `boost::multi_index` with an ordered or hashed index for fast lookup and a sequential index for traversing the parameters in the original config file order.

I haven't checked, that boost property map could do that from what I've heard.

It is possible to store all values as strings (or arrays of strings for array values)   converting them to the destination type only when accessing it.